# How to set IAM role with MrJob 0.4.2 on EMR

Tags: python, emr, mrjob

I'm trying to set an IAM role to my EMR cluster with mrjob 0.4.2.
I saw that there is a new option in 0.4.3 to do this, but it is still in development and I prefer to use the stable version instead.

Any idea on how to do this? I have tried to create the cluster using Amazon's console and then run the bootstrap+step actions using mrjob (by connecting to that cluster) but it didn't worked.

Another option is being able to change the default permissions for EMR instances so mrjob will be able to take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after many searches, it seems there is no such option